# Browsing Bombs After a Short While

Tags: windows-vista, internet, wireless-networking, sony-vaio, nsis

After a reboot, my internet connection lasts perhaps a half hour or so before tanking. I can ping (by both IP and hostname), but I cannot browse. If I restart the "Network Store Interface Service", my connection comes back. What could be failing with that service or its dependent services that would kill my ability to browse?

For some system info, I'm using a Sony Vaio with a fully-patched Windows Vista install and with an Intel 3945ABG wireless adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified you have the latest drivers and have you tried other browsers? It could be a plugin to your browser so you might want to check they are up to date as well.